# Defining geometry type in QgsDataSourceUri

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geometry

There is a PostgreSQL database containing some layers that have few types of geometry (multipolygons and linestrings). I need to distinguish these geometries in two separate layers.

My basic strings that make layer for QGIS are:

```
uri.setConnection('srs', '5432', 'db_name', 'postgres' , 'password') 
for i, name in enumerate(sorted(list_of_layers)): # list containing elements like ['schema_name', 'layer_name']
    if name[1] in ['layer_with_geometry_collection']:
        uri.setDataSource(name[0], name[1], 'SP_GEOMETRY')
        vlayer=QgsVectorLayer (uri.uri(), name[1], "postgres")
```

Where do I need to set the geometry type?
If I check `vlayer.wkbType()`, it throws me `0`.
Manual set `uri.setWkbType()` hadn't helped yet.

Comment: It is very dangerous to casually connect to an RDBMS as the administrative user. Doing so can often result in casual destruction of the database. Instead, create a login user to own your data, and another to manage read-only or read-mostly connections. The `postgres` user should never own spatial data.

Comment: @Vince you mean not to use `postgres` as a username?

Comment: Yes. Only connect as postgres to create new login and group roles.

Answer (score 3):

Found an answer in PosGIS reference guide.
According to [types of geometry](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryType.html) that can be stored in PostGIS database, a filter should be written to get the specific geometry.

For example, I need to get only polygon features. The full code will be:

```
filter = """ST_GeometryType("{}")  LIKE '{}'""".format('SP_GEOMETRY', 'ST_Polygon')
uri.setConnection('srs', '5432', 'db_name', 'postgres' , 'password') 
for i, name in enumerate(sorted(list_of_layers)): # list containing elements like ['schema_name', 'layer_name']
    if name[1] in ['layer_with_geometry_collection']:
        uri.setDataSource(name[0], name[1], 'SP_GEOMETRY', filter) # filter added
        vlayer=QgsVectorLayer (uri.uri(), name[1], "postgres")
```

Comment: You'd have to build a covering index to make this query performant, and doing do would conflict with use of a spatial index in the application.